# When I rotate a game object, it keeps moving the same direction

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, rigidbody

When I try to rotate my game object, it keeps moving in same direction. I think there is pretty basic solution but couldn't figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
private void Move()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector3( rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y, speed * forwardSpeedMultiplier * Time.deltaTime );

    float xVelocity = horizontalInput * speedMultiplier * horizontalSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    float yVelocity = -verticalInput * speedMultiplier * verticalSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    rb.velocity = Vector3.Lerp(rb.velocity,
        new Vector3(xVelocity, yVelocity, rb.velocity.z),
        Time.deltaTime * smoothness);
}
```

Note that I am using a rigidbody to move it.

I try to add `+ transform.forward` to the first line. It kind of works but it messes up the speed.
I know this is probably basic question but still would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you multiply a speed by a time interval, you get a distance, not a speed. So you should delete the `* Time.deltaTime` from every line where it's being multiplied by a speed parameter. (And then reduce your speed parameters by a factor of 30 or 60 so they're actually measuring speed correctly)

Now, it looks to me like you want to construct a new speed relative to the object's orientation, something like this:

```cs
// Compute velocity in local coordinates:
Vector3 targetVelocityLocal = new Vector3(
                                   horizontalInput * speedMultiplier,
                                  -verticalInput * speedMultiplier,
                                  speed * forwardSpeedMultiplier
                              );

// Rotate velocity into world coordinates:
Vector3 targetVelocityWorld = rb.rotation * targetVelocityLocal;

// Accelerate toward this velocity:
Vector3 deltaV = targetVelocityWorld - rb.velocity;

rb.AddForce(deltaV * smoothness * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```

Comment: It works now but it is jitry now

Comment: Is it safe to assume you're calling this in FixedUpdate, and have enabled interpolation on your Rigidbody? Have you tried reducing the value of the smoothness variable to give the body more inertia?

Comment: Yeah all that it checked it turned out I didn't use addForce correctly anyway it works now.